# Match numbers not following words or punctuation

Tags: regex, regex-lookarounds

I want to have regex that will match numbers that are not preceded by whitespace or punctuation, e.g.:

- foo12 -> matches 12
- foo 42 -> no match
- foo.42 -> no match

I came up with:
`(?<![[:space:][:punct:]])\d+`

However, this does not work as I intend, as for the examples, the results are as folllows:

- foo12 -> matches 12 (OK)
- foo 42 -> matches 2 (not OK)
- foo.42 -> matches 2 (not OK)

I understand, why it matches single digits in the last two examples (because negative-lookbehind includes only whitespace and punctuation), however I am not sure how to change my regex to exclude those matches. How can it be corrected?

Comment: Add `\d` to character class: `(?<![[:space:][:punct:]\d])\d+`

Comment: @revo I was sure I tried that! Can you add your comment as an answer, so that I can accept?

Comment: You seem to only want to match the number at the start of string or after a letter. You may then use `(?<![^[:alpha:]])\d+` / `(?<!\P{L})\d+`. See [this regex demo](https://regex101.com/r/vggvfW/1). Where are you using the regex?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The reason for partial match is that engine doesn't know exactly where it should start from regarding your requirements. You tell engine by including `\d` in character class:

```
(?<![[:space:][:punct:]\d])\d+
                       ^^
```

Answer (score 0):

[This RegEx](https://regex101.com/r/ruSstp/1/) might help you to divide your string input into two groups, where the second group (`$2`) is the target number and group one (`$1`) is the non-digit behind it:

```
([A-Za-z_+-]+)([0-9]+)
```

[image: RegEx]

It might be safe to do so, if you might want to use it for text-processing.